# When does Pirates of the Enchiridion actually auto-save?

Tags: adventure-time-pirates-enchiridion

The game informs you that it performs an auto-save when BMO icon pops out. But I've never seen it, and the game doesn't have a manual save feature, as far as I know.

So, how can I know that the game was saved recently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some testing, it seems that the game auto-saves quite often: when moving from an area to another, getting on and off the boat, progressing with a mission or when you pick up an item. And probably also after a battle.

Good to know, even if the BMO icon is never shown on screen.